# Apply InputFormatter to specify controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created a custom input formatter in C# and I'm trying to register it like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers(options =>
        {
            options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new CSPReportInputFormatter ());
        });
}

public class CSPReportInputFormatter : TextInputFormatter
{
    public CSPReportInputFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/csp-report"));
        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.UTF8);
    }

    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        using var reader = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body);
        string responseString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContentSecurityPolicyRequest>(responseString);

        return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(data);
    }
}
```

When I use AddControllers this media type is getting applied to all controllers available at the global level. I just want to apply to one particular controller and action method.

How can I do that?